# System ask password when push project to github

Tags: gitlab

I setup gitlab on `Centos 6x` . `Webserver : nginx` .

I installed my gitlab follow [link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos) .
And i have a problem : when i push my project on client to `gitlab@mydomain.com` , system ask password :

```
git push -u origin master

git@gitlab.mydomain.com's password:
```

Then i show config file of my project on client :

cat ../.git/config

> [core]
>
> ```
>    repositoryformatversion = 0
>    filemode = true
>    bare = false
>    logallrefupdates = true
> ```
>
> [branch "master"]
>
> [remote "origin"]
>
> ```
>     url = git@gitlab.mydomain.com:myusename/myproject.git
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

System showed log When i check :

bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>
> Checking Environment ...
>
> ..
>
> ..

I want to turn off the password requirement .

Some body help me , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have checked you public keys are valid and installed on client and server/gitlab and that ssh is working with public keys for another user on that machine.

Have you checked file permissions on the git users  ~/.ssh directory (should be 700) and  ~/.ssh/authorised_keys (600).

Also is selinux enabled? You may have an issue with security contexts - see  https://serverfault.com/a/564824/204206