# Password for GitLab

Tags: linux, git, centos, gitlab

I've installed GitLab per https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos.

The instructions state to add user "git"

```
adduser --system --shell /sbin/nologin --comment 'GitLab' --create-home --home-dir /home/git/ git
```

All seemed to work.  I then added a project on the GitLab server, and it gave instructions to push to it:

```
cd existing_git_repo
git remote add origin git@mysite.com:root/bidjunction.git
git push -u origin master
```

I then went to my client to push to the git server.

```
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'mysite.com (123.456.789.01)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is cd:32:3c:5a:4e:33:44:11:df:ee:3s:4b:3a:c2:a4:c2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'mysite.com,123.456.789.01' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Address 123.456.789.01 maps to ve6.phpwebhosting.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
git@mysite.com's password:
```

Is there a password I should have set?  Probably not, and instructions don't address.

Reading [System ask password when push project to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111760/system-ask-password-when-push-project-to-github), it appears it might be related to SSH.

GitLab provides the following instructions to add a SSH key.  I followed them, and first added the key to my general user's home on the server.  No change.  Then tried logging on a root, and added a key to git's home.  Still none, but I am thinking that the client already has my general user's key, thus is not pulling the new git key.

EDIT.  Please confirm that I should add these keys to the GitLab server, and not my Linux client.

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

```
SSH Keys

SSH key allows you to establish a secure connection between your computer and GitLab

Before generating an SSH key, check if your system already has one by running cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub If your see a long string starting with ssh-rsa or ssh-dsa, you can skip the ssh-keygen step.

To generate a new SSH key just open your terminal and use code below. The ssh-keygen command prompts you for a location and filename to store the key pair and for a password. When prompted for the location and filename you can press enter to use the default. It is a best practice to use a password for an SSH key but it is not required and you can skip creating a password by pressing enter. Note that the password you choose here can't be altered or retrieved.

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"

Use the code below to show your public key.

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Copy-paste the key to the 'My SSH Keys' section under the 'SSH' tab in your user profile. Please copy the complete key starting with ssh- and ending with your username and host.
```

EDIT 2

Looks like I was confused, and used GitLab's server id_rsa.pub.  Guess that doesn't make any sense!  I've since corrected it, but now I get this error:

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ ssh git@mysite.com
Address 123.456.789.01 maps to ve6.phpwebhosting.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
This account is currently not available.
                                        Connection to mysite.com closed.
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a SELinux permission issue. Steps to follow:

1. `restorecon -R -v /home/git/.ssh`
2. `usermod -s /bin/bash git`
3. Edit your home machine user's `.ssh/config` to something like:

> ```
> Host mysite.com
>   User gitlab_username
>   Hostname mysite.com
>   PreferredAuthentications publickey
>   IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
> ```

Try connecting to the gitlab server `ssh -T git@mysite.com`. You should see a message welcoming you.

I added it to the installation guide. I have a [merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/merge_requests/13) ready with several enhancements. I will merge it when gitlab 6.8 is released.

Comment: Thanks axil.  Currently, I have SELinux in permissive mode.  Please see my EDIT 2 on my original post.  Thoughts?  I made the changes to .ssh/config as suggested.  Do this to the client, not the GitLab server, correct?  Got error `Bad owner or permissions on /home/Michael/.ssh/config`.  Which user should I be using?  Git?  My client user?  Thank you!

Comment: That's correct. You should be using the user with which you sign in to gitlab. There is an updated guide for CentOS btw :)

Comment: Thanks Axil,  I will start over following the updated guide, and see what happens.  How far back do you think I need to go (i.e. should I `yum remove` anything)?  Also, I have been configuring Apache differently than recommended by the guide.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227851/configuring-apache-on-centos-for-gitlab.  Thank you

Comment: I don't think you would need to uninstall anything.

Comment: Thanks again Axil,  Did you have a chance to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227851/configuring-apache-on-centos-for-gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up your global config username and email

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the git user has a no login shell as you specified.  Changing that to bash as suggested fixed my problem (`usermod -s /bin/bash git`).